# How a variable list to filter data using sql python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, filter

I am trying to filter data using a variable list **ABC**.

This variable list has about 25 000 itens.

My first approach was the use of for loop, so I filtered each element of list but it's too slow!

```
script="""SELECT CODUSU, DOS, TIP, DTD FROM Dose WHERE (CODUSU IN ('"""+abc[i]+"""')) AND (DTD LIKE '%"""+str(anofinal)+"""')   ;"""
```

Now I think it's better to use something like:

```
script="""SELECT CODUSU, DOS, TIP, DTD FROM Dose WHERE (CODUSU IN ('06LA006','06LA005')) AND (DTD LIKE '%"""+str(anofinal)+"""')    ;"""
```

But I am not finding how to pass a list argument inside my script.

What I have tried until now:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Tecnico\Desktop\Backup\be.mdb;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

abc=['06LA006','06LA005','13JA001']
script="""SELECT CODUSU, DOS, TIP, DTD FROM Dose WHERE (CODUSU IN ("""%abc""")) AND (DTD LIKE '%"""+str(anofinal)+"""') ;"""
df1 = pd.read_sql_query(script, conn)
banco=banco.append(df1)
print(df1)
        
        
banco.to_csv('20'+str(anofinal)+'_d.csv',sep=";", index = False)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
abc=['dw','wda','wiug87']
for ele in abc:
    script="""SELECT CODUSU, DOS, TIP, DTD FROM Dose WHERE (CODUSU LIKE ele) AND 
    (DTD LIKE '%"""+str(anofinal)+"""') ;"""
```

> buddy I dont know if it'll work but I tried

Comment: This was the loop solution. It takes about 2 minutes for each 100 loops